# Code Look/Runs fine but no changes are made

Tags: delphi

I have the following code, all the code needs to do is go through a list of vehicles and remove the spaces in each registration but before changing it, it should check to make sure the ammended registration doesn't exist. The following code is what I am using:

```
unit Main;
interface

uses
 Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
 Dialogs, Menus, cxLookAndFeelPainters, StdCtrls, cxButtons, Gauges, DB,
 DBTables, StrUtils;

type
TfrmMain = class(TForm)
  prgTotal: TGauge;
  btnStart: TcxButton;
  tblVeh: TTable;
  tblVehRegNo: TStringField;
  procedure btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
private
  procedure OpenTable(pTable: TTable);
  procedure CloseTable(pTable: TTable; pPost: Boolean);
  { Private declarations }
public
  { Public declarations }
end;

var
  frmMain   : TfrmMain;
  lvRegLst  : TStringList;
  lvTblSize : Integer;
  lvOrigReg : String;
  lvNewReg  : String;
  lvTest    : integer;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TfrmMain.btnStartClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  btnStart.Enabled := False;
  lvRegLst  := TStringList.Create;

  // Open Tables
  tblVeh.Open;
  tblVeh.First;

  // Set progress
  prgTotal.MinValue := 0;
  lvTblSize         := tblVeh.RecordCount;
  prgTotal.MaxValue := tblVeh.RecordCount;
  btnStart.Caption  := 'Parsing Registration Numbers...';

  // Conversion
  while not tblVeh.Eof do
  begin
    lvRegLst.Add(tblVehRegNo.AsString);
    tblVeh.Next;
    prgTotal.AddProgress(1);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;

  tblVeh.First;
  lvTest            := lvRegLst.Count;
  prgTotal.Progress := 0;
  btnStart.Caption  := 'Removing Spaces...';

  while not tblVeh.Eof do
  begin
    lvOrigReg := tblVehRegNo.AsString;
    lvNewReg  := AnsiReplaceStr(lvOrigReg,' ','');

    if lvRegLst.IndexOf(lvNewReg) = -1 then
    begin
      tblVeh.Edit;
      tblVehRegNo.AsString := lvNewReg;
      prgTotal.AddProgress(1);
      tblVeh.Post;
    end;

    tblVeh.Next;
    prgtotal.AddProgress(1);
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;

  // Close Tables
  tblVeh.Edit;
  tblVeh.Post;
  tblVeh.Close;

  btnStart.Caption := '&Start Conversion';
  btnStart.Enabled := True;
end;
```

I have stepped through the code and all looks fine and it successfuly changes the registration against the vehicle but when looking at the table afterwards it's not made any changes.

Comment: Couldn't see anything wrong with the code so far. If I was facing this kind of issue (which I sometimes do) and was unable to spot a problem in the client code, I would try using a profiler to see what was happening on the server side. (An example of a server side cause would be a trigger on the table.)

Comment: One other thing could be that the code doesn't really change anything, i.e. not one of the registrations contains any spaces.

Comment: And by the way, do you realise that your code would update the progress bar twice whenever it had something to update? I'm talking about two `prgTotal.AddProgress(1);` entries in the second loop, one in the table edit branch and the other just after `tblVeh.Next;`.

Comment: Other than the fact that you have an unnecessary `tblVeh.Edit; tblVeh.Post;` immediately before the `tblVeh.Close;` statement at the end, and you use the horrid `Application.ProcessMessages;` (you should use `prgTotal.Update;` instead), the code looks fine. Do you actually have registrations with spaces in them?

Comment: Do you know how to use the debugger to step through code and inspect variables?

Comment: @Moon what type of object is tblVeh?

Comment: Where does tblVehRegNo get a value?

Comment: @KenWhite Thank you, I have amended my code. What are the the implications for using 'Application.ProcessMessages' instead of the alternative that you have suggested?

Comment: `PM` has a lot of overhead, and empties the entire message loop every time it is called. It can cause problems with reentrancy (code being run multiple times) unless you're careful. Using `PB.Update` instead just updates the progress bar, which is much quicker and avoids that issue. If you need to have more of the UI responsive during a very long process, you should be using a separate thread instead of the main thread to do that work; your code looks short enough and to be dealing with a small enough amount of data to just update the progress bar and get done quickly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the database itself, it turns out 'RegNo' is the only key field so it's the default index. As my conversion was running through it was changing registrations which moved the 'cursor' and skipped over a number of registrations.

I have added another index for the purpose of this conversion but making around 50-60 passes over their data would have eventually sorted out all of the registrations.

Thank you for all of the help.

Comment: Yep, that is indeed one of the many drawbacks of using meaningful primary keys. Had you had a meaningless primary key (some sort of GUID or sequential numbering using triggers, generators or whatever the db provides for this) and the RegNo as an secondary key, you would not have run into this.

Comment: No wonder we couldn't find anything in your code; I was starting to doubt myself that I could not see the error ;-)